# Why does the paho python client publish short messages but not long ones

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

This works :

```
while True:
    print('')
    command_input = input()
    if command_input == 'q':
        break
    mcp = Mqtt_command_publisher
    mcp.publish_command(device_ids, command_input)
```

But this does not:

```
class Mqtt_command_bl:
    def update_minutes_to_run_at(json):
        if not json['device_ids']:
            return 'Request must contain device ids'

        device_ids = json['device_ids']
        minutes_to_run_at = json['minutes_to_run_at']

        minutes_to_run_at_command_section = ''
        for i in minutes_to_run_at:
            m = '"{}",'.format(i)
            if i == minutes_to_run_at[len(minutes_to_run_at) - 1]:
                m = '"{}"'.format(i)
            minutes_to_run_at_command_section += m

        #command_input = 'jq \'.+{{minutes_to_run_at:[{}]}}\' /home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/config.json > /home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/tmp.json && mv /home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/tmp.json /home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/new_config.json'.format(minutes_to_run_at_command_section)
        command_input = 'mkdir /home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/hello_world'

        mcp = Mqtt_command_publisher
        mcp.publish_command(device_ids, command_input)

        return 'Success'
```

The class they both call:

```
class Mqtt_command_publisher:
    def publish_command(device_ids, command_input):
        mqtt_msg = json.dumps({'device_ids':device_ids,'command':command_input})
        print('\n{}'.format(mqtt_msg))
        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.connect('********', ****, 30)
        client.publish('topic/commands', mqtt_msg)
        client.disconnect()
```

Looking at the print statements output from the Mqtt_command_publisher, the output can be the exact same, however, only one of them will execute, and I don't see why one works and the other does not.

I tried this command for testing: `mkdir /home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/hello_world`

This is the receiving part:

```
device_id = 0

with open('/home/pi/hallmonitor_lite/config.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)

    device_id = data['device_id']

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code: " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("topic/commands")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    mqtt_message = msg.payload.decode()
    print(mqtt_message)
    ids_and_command = json.loads(mqtt_message)
    if str(device_id) in ids_and_command['device_ids'] or not ids_and_command['device_ids']:
        print(('Executing: {}').format(ids_and_command['command']))
        os.system(ids_and_command['command'])



client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("********", ****, 30)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's in device_ids in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely because the second set of code is creating a message bigger than will fit in a single TCP packet.

This is a problem because you are not running the client network loop so the `client.publish` command can only send a single packet, the rest of the message would have been sent by the network loop, but even if it was running you are calling disconnect immediately after the publish call.

The client is not meant to be spun up for a single message like that, it is meant to be started and then left running with you just calling the `publish` method when you want to send a message. If you don't want to do that or can't for some reason there is a specific helper class in the paho python package that will do all the heavy lifting of starting the client, sending the message and then tearing everything down nicely. The docs for the single publish are [here](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#single).

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("paho/test/single", "payload", hostname="mqtt.eclipse.org")
```

Comment: Ah, the issue was a stupid logic error on my part, the issue was `if str(device_id)` in the subscriber, i just needed to remove the str() part and it worked. Dont remember why I did the conversion to string initially, but thank you for your feedback regardless, and i did take your suggestion to do a publish.single instead.